Changes to dist Folder Not Reflecting in Custom vue-business-hours Package After Modifying Source Code
I'm working in a project with vue and docker and the scripts in package.json has:
 "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "dev": "quasar dev",
    "build-mac": "quasar build -d -m electron -T mac -b builder -P never",
    "build-linux": "quasar build -d -m electron -T linux -b builder -P never",
    "build-win": "quasar build -d -m electron -T win -b builder -P never",
    "build-win32": "quasar build -d -m electron -T win32 -b builder -P never",
    "deploy-mac": "quasar build -d -m electron -T mac -b builder -P always",
    "deploy-linux": "quasar build -d -m electron -T linux -b builder -P always",
    "deploy-win": "quasar build -d -m electron -T win -b builder -P always",
    "deploy-win32": "quasar build -d -m electron -T win32 -b builder -P always",
    "prepare": "husky"
  }

apart of that, into the dependencies I have a package that it's a fork of https://github.com/sbarry50/vue-business-hours. This fork we have in the github of the company.
In the dependencies of the project I have:
"vue-business-hours": "github:company/vue-business-hours#feature-business-hours"

where #feature-business-hours is the new branch that I pushed some new changes, the problem here is that I removed all images, containers and volumes in docker and I rebuilt everything, then I run yarn add github:company/vue-business-hours#feature-business-hours but I can't see my new changes in the project and I noticed that my changes there is no exists in dist folder, so I don't know if I need to run another command in yarn or if another thing the problem.
I don't know if I can add more extra information of the issue
